# Extracting values for the entire spreadsheet using Range.Value produces unexpected result

Tags: excel, vba

When using `Range.Value` to extract the values from the entire spreadsheet into a 2-dimensional array of Variant, many cells containing numeric values are skipped, leaving elements of the array empty.

The code below executes the `Range.Value` method and then creates a text file containing what should be the value of each cell in the spreadsheet, tab delimited with each row on its own line.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim spreadsheetArray As Variant

Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(spreadsheetName)

lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

' Copy the values from the spreadsheet into a 2 dimensional array of Variant

spreadsheetArray = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value

Open "excel.txt" For Append As #1 ' Open file for output.

Print #1, "Array for sheet " & spreadsheetName & ", rows=" & UBound(spreadsheetArray, 1) & ", columns=" & UBound(spreadsheetArray, 2)

Dim r, c As Long
Dim line As String

' Each cell's value is delimited by a tab and each row is delimited by CR/LF
For r = 1 To UBound(spreadsheetArray, 1)
    line = Str(r) & Chr(9)
    
    For c = 1 To UBound(spreadsheetArray, 2)
        line = line & spreadsheetArray(r, c) & Chr(9)
    Next c
    
    Print #1, line
Next r

Close #1
```

After the above has run, I open the resulting text file in a text editor, copy everything to the clipboard and paste it into a new spreadsheet containing only the values.  This makes it easy to compare the original spreadsheet with the reproduced (value only) spreadsheet.  The results are not what I expected.

Here is the original spreadsheet (the one the code runs against):

[image]

And after pasting the contents of the resulting `excel.txt` file into a new sheet, I get this:

[image]

Why didn't the values of so many cells that clearly contain values not make it into the array produced by `Range.Value`?

UPDATE:

Nearly all the missing data came from cells that contain a UDF.  The only exception is that hexadecimal stuff on the Control row.  That hex stuff is produced by a UDF.  But why should it matter to `Range.Value` if a cell contains a UDF?  It has an evaluated value and Excel is correctly displaying it, so why doesn't `Range.Value` pick up the value?

Comment: Does opening the text file directly in excel change the outcome?

Comment: @TimWilliams No... you can see the data is missing from within the text editor (EditPlus).  It's just prettier when looking at it in Excel.  `Range.Value` definitely skips some, but not all, of the cells it encounters.

Comment: If you query the array `spreadsheetArray` directly, does it not contain the values from those cells?  Are the missing cells all formulas?

Comment: @TimWilliams I do query the array directly, in the line of code that's in the nested loop: `line = line & spreadsheetArray(r, c)`

Comment: Are you able to share a worksheet (suitable redacted) which can be used for testing?

Comment: @TimWilliams I could, but it would be a lot of work.  Maybe I'll do that in a week or so if I don't get this resolved first.

Comment: I'm going to try `Range.Text`.  I'll report back.

Comment: `Range.Text` doesn't populate an array, so back to `Range.Value`.

Comment: I set up a sheet which sort-of looks like your screenshot, but didn't see any issues.

Comment: Try `spreadsheetArray = ws.Range("M38:N39").Value`, let's see what's in the text file.

Comment: Maybe consider copying the sheet, paste special values (or vba equivalent) and then run it on that to test if it's the UDF causing the issue..?